# Strange offset between VoiceOver Focus and Firefox Focus

Tags: firefox, voiceover, focus

## What happens

When I use VoiceOver (VO) together with Firefox (FF) (doesn't matter if I have all extensions disabled, even tried to run it with a completely fresh install of FF developer edition.) Then the VO focus seems to have an offset applied to it that puts it out of alignment with where the focus *should* be (the FF focus gets it right). I have tried to supply a picture of what happens (It's a picture of the screen due to the fact that it's hard to take a screenshot of VO focus).

[image: showing the misalignment of VoiceOver focus and Firefox focus]

## What I tried

### check if the issue exists on *other* browsers

I tried Chrome, and the issue is not present. In my head this isolates the issue to some interaction between Firefox and VoiceOver.

### Try with a *clean* Firefox install

I tried to boot my existing FF holding down the `option` key, this puts it into [troubleshooting mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/diagnose-firefox-issues-using-troubleshoot-mode), so it runs without addons and customizations. Still the issue persists. In my head this isolates it to something between VO and "default" FF. So nothing I did to FF afaik.

### Try to reset VoiceOver

I've tried to delete all data I could find regarding VO itself (at least what I considered "safe to remove" through web search). This meant the preferences data related to VO in `~/Library/Preferences`.

To wipe this I did the following:

```
la -1 ~/Library/Preferences | grep -i voiceover | xargs rm -rf
```

Still the issue persists, and now is when I feel I'm running out of options on how to narrow this issue down any further. It seems to me to happen with "default" Firefox and (to my best effort) "default" VoiceOver. Other coworkers with the a mac do not have the same issue, so I think it's some setting somewhere on my mac that causes this. But again, I'm not sure.